# How to know when a user has left the page and refreshed the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make an AJAX call before the user leaves the page (so basically before leaving the page and before refreshing the page)?

How can this be done. I was trying to search something with jQuery but didnt get anything.

I tried to use the following code -

```
window.onbeforeunload(function(){alert('before unload');});
```

But the alert box never appears when leaving the page(closing the browser tab) or refreshing the page.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: onBeforeUnload, to my knowledge, was an IE event. others browsers may have implemented it, but nothing definite. Maybe explain the purpose and we can come to an alternate solution? Catching a user leaving is quite difficult...

Comment: PS, [MDN onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload). Likewise, the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536907%28VS.85%29.aspx) on it.

Comment: Brad - I am doing some tracking relating to YouTube videos like the actual duration a user has watched the video. For this, I am using a sampling rate (like 5 seconds) and updating a global JS variable which needs to be sent to the server when the video ends. Also, the user can leave / reload the page after watching a part of it (before reaching the end of the video). So I need to know when the user leaves / reloads the page so that I can make the AJAX call to the server. Also, wanted to ask if this the recommended way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(window).unload(function() {
    alert('Visitor left page');
});
```

Regarding the ajax call, you can do it, but you must set the `async` to `false`.

```
$.ajax({
   async: false,
   ...
 });
```

Comment: its worth noting this doesn't work on some devices, like the iPad

Answer (score 7):

You should try [unload()](http://api.jquery.com/unload/) from jquery:

```
$(window).unload(function(){
   //Do your call
   alert('before unload');
  });
```

oro you could use the beforeunload event. You should test it well because browser tend to imlement those things differently. taken from jquery documentation:

> The exact handling of the unload event has varied from version to
>   version of browsers. For example, some versions of Firefox trigger the
>   event when a link is followed, but not when the window is closed. In
>   practical usage, behavior should be tested on all supported browsers,
>   and contrasted with the proprietary beforeunload event.

Comment: Thanks! This solution works for me. I see the Alert box when I refresh the page as well as when the close the window / browser tab. I just need to ask that of I do an ajax call there, can I be sure that my server will get the call - I don't have to worry about the response.

Comment: Well if you put the call before the alert box you will be pretty sure that the call reaches your server.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is simply wrong. The unbeforeunload is used to ask the person if he really want to leave the page.
You need unload.

```
window.onunload = function() {
  // Make your AJAX call

}
```

Better use jQuery.unload() method

Comment: Did that using JQuery. Please help me with the comment I posted on the above answer.