# Ruby on Rails - Check if other Editor is editing same post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, notifications

I have a application where **authors** can post a content and **all editors** can `edit` all contents that has been added on website.

Sometimes 2-3 editors are editing the same post and it has made some issues. Is it possible to see if other editors are on the same `edit view/ post/edit` and editing same post?

What I would like to do is to add a notification that says `[Editor_name] is changing this post` or something similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks everybody for their answer. Based on all answers I made what I needed. Other answers were great but little more complicated for what I wanted to achieve.

*Here is what I did*

**Add migration for adding two new columns to post database**

```
add_column :posts, :current_editor, :integer
add_column :posts, :editing_started_at, :timestamp
```

**In posts controller**

```
private
def currently_editing(editor, time)
  @post.current_editor = editor
  @post.editing_started_at = time
  @post.save
end
```

**In posts controller, edit action**

```
currently_editing(current_user.id, Time.zone.now) if @post.current_editor.nil?
```

**In posts controller, create action**

```
if @post.current_editor == current_user.id
  currently_editing(nil, nil) if updating?
  currently_editing(nil, nil) if publishing?
end
```

I also added a **Cancel edit** in `edit#posts` view. If user didn't want to change anything.

```
- if @post.current_editor == current_user.id
  = link_to 'Cancel Edit', post_path(@post, 'post[current_editor]' => '', 'post[editing_started_at]' => ''), method: :put
```

**Showing notification to other editor that want to edit same post**

```
- if @post.current_editor != current_user.id
  %p Somebody else is editing this post now
```

Comment: What happens if the user does not use the provided back button, but the back button from the browser? Your solution works, but for this specific usecase it fails. So how did you handle that usecase?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **optimistic locking**. The idea is that every record has a *lock version*. Each successful update increments the lock version of that record. When you update a record, the lock version is verified. The update will fail if the version of your model is different than the version of that record in the database, which means the record has been changed by someone else between the time you load that record from the database and your attempt to update to that record.

To implement optimistic locking in ActiveRecord is easy. All you need to do is add a column `lock_version` to your model.

**Migration**

```
add_column :posts, :lock_version, :integer
```

Comment: You did leave out that you have to add `lock_version` to the update form. Furthor more it does only track modifications on the record. This does not mean that an edit did happen. It can be for instance a touch or a background process.

Comment: @slowjack2k I don't think you should do this, because the workflow is **load record from DB to a model**, **assign new values to its fields**, **save it back to DB**. The field `lock_version` is loaded from database anyway.

Comment: I think the workflow is Editor A loads the post and edit it. Editor B loads the post and edit it. Editor B load and saves the post within update action. Editor A load and saves the post within update action. When editors B post is saved before Editor A loads its post both posts are saved because the `lock_version` looks ok. Your version works only when Editor B loads its record, Editor A loads its record, Editor B save its record and then `save`fails for editor A.

Answer (score 1):

You need a new model like `PostEditor` that combines `Post` and `User` in an `m*n` relation (I know it's unlikely a single user edits more than one post at the same time, but I think it should be possible).

In your `PostsController` you need to create that connection in the `edit` action. And you need to remove the connection when either the user saves the post or leaves the page (look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821870/how-to-know-when-a-user-has-left-the-page-and-refreshed-the-page) for more on that).

Additionally you need some repeating `Ajax` calls to your database, while the `User` edits a `Post` and show an info, when another user is added to the `PostEditor` list of that `Post`.

And finally when saving you should check, if the `Post` was saved since the current `User` started to edit it, cancel the save process and show a `diff` of the two versions or something like that. And of course you need to `synchronize` your `update` method with a `Mutex`.

I hope this gives you an idea of what to do :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you add the following colums to your table `lock_version` for optimistic locking to prevent race conditions. `current_editor_id` to have a reference to the current editor. `editing_started_at` to have a reference if the current editor is still "alive".

When a editor starts editing you have to check if `current_editor` is the actual editor or not set. If `current_editor` is `nil` or the `current_editor` and `editor` are the same or if the time limit is reached via `editing_started_at` this editor can start editing.

When editing starts you set `current_editor`, `editing_started_at` and save the object.

When an editor trys to save an `post` you check once again if `current_editor` and editor matches. Then you can save the post
and update `current_editor` and `editing_started_at` to nil.

In other cases you can print an error messages.